# Why would Chain of Responsibility be inappropriate when there is only one handler for each request?

Tags: design-patterns, usb, chain-of-responsibility

I am currently working on USB firmware for a project. While figuring out how to best handle servicing requests from the host, I decided to implement a Chain of Responsibility pattern.

In my application, there will always be exactly one handler for each request retrieved from the host. So basically I set up my handler chain ahead of time and the loop starts with waiting for a request from the host. The request is passed to the "root" handler who decides, by examining part of the request, whether to handle it or pass it down the chain. Once the request is handled, we loop back to waiting for another request from the host.

Again, only one handler will ever handle a request. A request not being handled, i.e., traversing the entire handler chain, is an error condition.

After reading up on the Chain of Responsibility pattern from [www.sourcemaking.com](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility), this quote caught my eye (last paragraph in the Discussion section):

> Do not use Chain of Responsibility when each request is only handled by one handler, or, when the client object knows which service object should handle the request.

Is there a good practical reason why this is true? It seems to me that using Chain of Responsibility in the case the author warns against is perfectly valid. Could anyone give me some insight on why this would be a bad design choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the warning you quoted was worded badly and could cause some confusion.  I think the author meant to say:

> Do not use Chain of Responsibility when all the requests will be handled by just one handler, or when the client object knows which service object should handle the request.

Another way of saying this is that the Chain of Responsibility pattern introduces some complexity and you should only use that complexity if you actually have multiple handlers, and if it is not easy for the client object to know which handler to use.  If you know only have one handler, there is no need for chain or a pointer because you know exactly what object to pass the request to.  If you have multiple handler but it's easy to look at the request and tell what object will handle it using simple "if" statements, then again you do not need a chain or a pointer.

Aside:  As someone who has implemented USB firmware on several platforms, I don't think you need anything so formal as a chain of responsibility.  I also think you don't even need pointers.  You can use simple if statements and hard-coded callbacks from the USB stack to the user code in order to direct each incoming control transfer to the appropriate code that can handle it.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. @DavidGrayson, "You can use simple if statements and hard-coded callbacks from the USB stack to the user code in order to direct each incoming control transfer to the appropriate code that can handle it." Can you elaborate on what you mean here?

Comment: You can look at [this USB stack](https://github.com/pololu/wixel-sdk/blob/master/libraries/src/usb/usb.c) and see how when a new control transfer is started, it either calls usbStandardDeviceRequestHandler or usbCallbackSetupHandler depending on the values in the control transfer.  The latter function must be defined in any application using the USB stack.

Comment: thanks for the link! I have seen similar examples from the manufacturer of the platform we are using. However, I have requirements which require runtime flexibility of how/when requests are handled. This was one of the reasons I went w/ CoR. Thanks again for your input!